# Facebook thinks my Admin ID is my App ID for Open Graph, calls it invalid

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I created a page and put the account name (from `facebook.com/<account-name>`) of the page in the `fb:admins` field and left the App ID field blank. When i test the Like button it says the App ID is invalid and lists the ID number of the page (note, there is no app, this is just a normal page). I also tried putting in the ID number that I get from `graph.facebook.com/<account-name>` and still it doesn't work. Running the Linter (`https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug`) shows the error: "You put ### in the fb:admins field. It should be in fb:app_id"...still, no app exists so I don't know why it thinks the ID is an app ID.

When I put a different user's ID in the admin ID field it works fine, but not if I'm following it using a page.

Comment: Your user ID is the number returned by `graph.facebook.com/<account-name>` - try that one again, and check the URL debug tool ( https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug ) to check if Faccebook is picking it up correctly

Also check that your og:url tab points to the correct URL - if it's pointing to a different URL, Facebook will check the tags on that URL also so it may not be easy to see if the correct tags are being picked up

Comment: That's what I was thinking too but that number hasn't been working. That debug tool shows that same number so I know it's not a caching issue.

Comment: Oh, I misread your question, Colm's answer is correct - i thought you were using a user ID, not a page ID

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this [doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/). You can't use a `page_id` to administer a page, you can only use a `UID` or an `AppID`. The `fb:page_id` is related to Insights, not OG administration.

Comment: I figured that was the answer but I needed confirmation. Thanks!